# "Control may reach end of non-void function" and recursivity

Tags: c++

This function takes two numbers, and recursively increases one of them by a specific amount to see if they eventually match. (The point is to check if two chessmen are on the same diagonal).

However, the warning *"Control may reach end of non-void function"* appears whereas there is an "else" statement to always return something.

```
bool pursue_recursive_increasing(int searcher, int target, int increment)
{
if (searcher==target)
    return true;
else if (searcher<target)
    pursue_recursive_increasing(searcher+increment, target, increment);
else
    return false;
}
```

Comment: There's no `return` in the `else if` block.

Comment: I'm afraid your guess is wrong; the compiler is right. There is no return statement in the `else if` block.

Comment: `return` only returns from a single level of recursion. Thus you need it at every level of recursion, not only at the most nested one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool pursue_recursive_increasing(int searcher, int target, int increment)
{
    if (searcher==target)
        return true;

    if (searcher>=target) // or, !(searcher < target)
        return false;

    return pursue_recursive_increasing(searcher+increment, target, increment);
}
```

Note that I tweaked your logic so that the recursive call is last and the simple anchor conditions are first; some people might find this slightly easier to follow.  This also makes it easier to spot a missing `return` at the end of your function; perhaps more importantly, it makes it easier for your compiler to do [tail-call optimization](https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/04/30/tail-call-optimisation-in-cpp/).

You should always assume that your compiler is right.

Comment: By moving the recursive call to the end of the function, it also gives the compiler an opportunity to employ [tail-call optimization](https://www.artificialworlds.net/blog/2012/04/30/tail-call-optimisation-in-cpp/) so the call stack doesn't overflow on long recursions.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that, if the `else if (searcher < target)` branch is executed, no value will be returned.

```cpp
bool pursue_recursive_increasing(int searcher, int target, int increment)
{
    if (searcher == target) {  // will return true
        return true;
    } else if (searcher < target) {  // will not return anything!
        pursue_recursive_increasing(searcher+increment, target, increment);
    } else /* searcher > target */ {  // will return false
        return false;
    }
}
```

I think what you want is to replace the `else if` branch with:

```cpp
return pursue_recursive_increasing(searcher+increment, target, increment);
```

so that it `return`s the value given by the recursive call.